# doit command color output issue

Tags: python, colors, doit

I am using doit tool for build.
Currently the issue I am facing is related to color output meaning when I call **doit** the output will start with color but end up without color.
However, when I run call it second time I will get colored output at the end without any issue.
Could someone assist? Is this related to a specific version of doit or some changes in confurations of dodo.py?

Regards

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programs usually try to detect if the output is a terminal or not and automatically turn-off color based on the result.

Usually the check is based on `isatty()` or `fileno()`.
doit `0.35` will have improved support on controlling this.

Comment: @sujan-shah please add a sample code on a github issue

Answer (score 0):

Using `doit.tools.Interactive` will preserve coloring.